# case insensitive search in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I use a little search script in my site.

After post the search form, i get this variable:

```
$var = $_GET[$q] ;
$trimmed = trim($var);
```

Then i try to search in database:

```
$query = "select * from test where acc like \"%$trimmed%\""; 
$numresults=mysql_query($query);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($numresults);
.......
```

I try to search for " test " word.  (In my database i have a row with " Test " word.) but found nothing. If i search " TEST " then nothing. Only then i get the result if i search exactly the word for in the database. (Test).

I read somewhere, that " LIKE " is case INsensitive.

Could you help me have can i modify the code, to search case Insensitive?

Thank you.

Comment: $var = $_GET[$q] --> Make sure to check the input data for injection attacks.

Comment: What is the collation for the acc field?

Comment: @Holian - Please heed KB22's comment, go read http://us2.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php if you don't know what he's talking about.

Answer (score 2):

[Doc on case sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html):

The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a. To make this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a case sensitive or binary collation. For example, if you are comparing a column and a string that both have the latin1 character set, you can use the COLLATE operator to cause either operand to have the latin1_general_cs or latin1_bin collation

Answer (score 1):

Case-sensitivity depends on the collation of your table:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE test`

That's a start - checking whether your table's case-sensitive or not.  I'll leave it to others to harp-on about how insecure your example code is.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

By the way, you should use the mysqli object to perform SQL request in PHP.